# JavaScript replace method doesn't erase closing tags, as coded in the regex, if it breaks nesting

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am sorry for the terrible question, hopefully someone can help me rephrase it, but check out my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var content = $('.content');
    var text = content.html();
    console.log(text);
    text = text.replace(/<span>/g, '');
    text = text.replace(/<\/span>/g, '');
    content.html(text);
    console.log(text, content.html());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tikitariki/cttmngzq/

Basically, I'm removing some HTML to clear up some styling. I use the `replace()` method to remove these `span` tags. However, from reading the docs, I don't understand why it doesn't remove the inside `</span>` tag in `<h3>`. I didn't *want* to remove it, that's my goal, but the code explicitly says to remove all `</span>`. In other words, it is working *too* well for what I want to use it for and I am not sure if this is expected behavior or not.

I'm using jQuery and Wordpress. I wasn't sure if they were related to this "bonus" feature.

```
<div class="content">
  <h1><span>Hey</span></h1>
  <h2><span>You</span></h2>
  <h3><span>I'm <span class="special">Special</span></span></h3>
</div>
```

The reason this is a question is because no documentation seems to reference this HTML tag protection ability of `replace()`. I like to use Mozilla's docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Don't use regex for this. jQuery has lots of methods for amending the DOM without hacking around text. What output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you are looking for <span>so the one with a clas sin it wont match

Comment: The `</span>` in the `<h3>` is removed but when adding the text back to the DOM `content.html(text);` there is still an opening `span` tag in the `<h3>` and the browser then needs to _recreate_ the missing `</span>`. You there relay on the error correction functionality of the browser.

Comment: @t.niese Okay, well that makes sense. I am using Chrome. Is that a built-in feature to close DOM elements? If you can provide a link or some documentation, that would be the answer to my question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan However, you did give me my desired outcome. If you want to edit your post and include how a browser might "auto-ammend" an unclosed DOM element

Comment: @Tarik  The browser parsers html and builds the DOM ou it. The DOM is a tree-based structure. A HTML Tag is a Node in that tree, as of that a DOMElement is neither open or closed. Requesting the html for a DOMElement the browser generates the HTML code out of that subtree you request, thats why tags will always match. While parsing to the DOM structure the browser is _fault-tolerant_, when it detects `</h3>` while it is currently in the node `span` it will check how to fix that error by either ignoring `</h3>` or leaving the `span` node. The HTML5 standard defines how to handle those errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use regex for this. jQuery has lots of methods for amending the DOM without hacking around text. Assuming you want to remove the `span` tags but retain the text within them it's a one-liner in jQuery:

```
$('.content span').not('.special').contents().unwrap();
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cttmngzq/3/)

Comment: Awesome solution, but how to I preserve the `<span>` inside the `<span>`? The Fiddle I posted was the desired solution, it just wasn't the expected behavior of the `replace` method.

Comment: @Tarik: `$('.content span:not(.special)').contents().unwrap();`

Comment: `$('.content>span').contents().unwrap();` or using more jQuery `$('.content').children('span').contents().unwrap();`

Comment: @gknicker The `span` tags aren't direct childs of `.content` so this selector won't work.

Answer (score -2):

If your goal is to remove the spans why not use jquery?

```
$('.content span').each( function () {
    // don't remove span with class special
    if ( $(this).hasClass( 'special' ) ) { return; }

    // if has a content replace this with the first child
    if ( this.firstChild ) {
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
    }
    // otherwise remove the span
    else {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cttmngzq/4/)

Comment: This will remove the `span` tags, but also the text within them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - you are right, I updated my answer ;-)